# Generate files using custom artisan make command Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to generate a class file using custom artisan make command.My command is showing under artisan make but I am not able to generate file 
What i did

1.Use `php artisan make:command CreateActionClass and implement GeneratorCommand`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class CreateActionClass extends GeneratorCommand
{  
protected $signature = 'make:action {name}';

protected $description = 'Create New Action Single Responsibility';

protected $type = 'Action';

public function handle()
{
    //
}

protected function getStub()
{       
    return  app_path().'/Console/Stubs/MakeActionStub.stub';
}

protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
{
    return $rootNamespace.'\Actions';
}
    protected function getArguments()
{
    return [
        ['name', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The name of the contract.'],
    ];
}}
```

2. Generate .stub file /Console/Stubs/MakeActionStub.stub

```
<?php
namespace DummyNamespace;
class DummyAction
{

}
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `handle` method. It is overriding the `GeneratorCommand` class's `handle` that's why its doing nothing. If you wish to extend the `handle` method, call `parent::handle()` before or after your statements